# How do I detect if the key of a variable is pressed?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I´m making a game that creates a random key that you have to press. I have an array with the letters from where it takes one randomly. I want to detect if the key is pressed so I did this:

`if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.lettre))`

but with `letter = "A"` for example, it will do this:

`if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode."A"))`

How do I get this?

`if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GetKey`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) can be called with a string, so you could just do:

```
if (Input.GetKey(letter)) // assuming letter is a string
```

You might need `letter` to be lowercase for this to work. See the list of key names [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html).

---

Alternatively, you could use [`Enum.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2) to convert your string to an enum value:

```
if (Input.GetKey((KeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(KeyCode), letter)))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used uppercase

Comment: @Mestik78 Can you use lowercase instead? If not, you can use the second approach.